# Problem with run commands in shell (bash) with arguments as variables !

Tags: bash, unix, shell

(Sorry for the confusion. Previous $ sign occurred when I tried to simplify the actual problem. Thanks for correcting the question)

I wanted to split a directory name on underscores (ex: dir_to_split="my_test_dir") like this:

```
my_dir=($dir_to_split)
var=$(echo $my_dir | awk -F"_" '{print $1,$2,$3}')   
set -- $var

splited_1=$1
splited_2=$2
splited_3=$3
```

now using these splited_x is causing me errors. ex.

```
myprograme $splited_1 $splited_2 $splited_3
```

Can anyone please help me with this ? Thank you....

Comment: This is confusing. Are you now saying that even after removing $ from first statement, it is still not working?

Comment: Sorry guys, above is the real example. $ sign error occurred when I tried to simplify the problem

Comment: What are the exact errors? It's rather hard to diagnose a problem without knowing what it is.

Comment: Actually, no errors in the display. But happening is $splited_1 is contain all the data as same as $dir_to_split and others (splited_x) don't.          Now I think, above spiting thing isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Rewritten after updated question.)

What kind of errors do you get? I find it useful to add `set -x` to the top of my shell scripts when debugging, this lets the shell print all commands it executes so you can pinpoint the line where problems begin.

Are you sure that `$dir_to_split` is actually set? Does it contain spaces or tabs? Does it contain two underscores? I don't see any other problems right now.

There are in-shell methods of splitting a variable such as:

```
dir="my_test_dir"
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS="-"
set --
IFS="$OIFS"
```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash).

Comment: I've corrected your answer's code example (I think it's now what you really mean)

Comment: In which case do you not mean: temp="app"
dir_name=$temp
mkdir $dir_name

Comment: @Delan: Thanks, just spotted it myself and was correcting it when I saw a nice popup appear.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake on posting the question. Actually I simplified the code, so pls let me try my original code.

Comment: $dir_to_split is actually set, and no spaces, tabs. but only underscores. Let me try your method.

Comment: hey ! how can I then access the individual elements in that array, without that for loop ?

Comment: @Morpheus: Your elements are still `$1`, `$2`, etc.